# Jupyter Pandas DataFrame - reading column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a snippet of python code that reads the values for SQL columns for a given row. The snippet below simply iterates thru columns within a DataFrame context and appends the numeric values to an array.

If i print out the value of each column, the output looks correct. However, if I print out the final array, then i see weird formatting (metadata).

```
values = []
for i in range(len(columns)):
        val = df[columns[i]];        
        values.append(val)
        #print(values) // this prints out the correct numeric value.

    #print(values) // but this prints out the array with the weird format.
```

The weird/metadata output looks like the following:

```
[0    0
Name: colname1, dtype: int64, 0    8
Name: colname2, dtype: int64, 0    0
Name: colname3, dtype: int64, 0    0
Name: colname4, dtype: int64, 0    0
Name: colname5, dtype: int64, 0    0
Name: colname6, dtype: int64, 0    0
Name: colname7, dtype: int64, 0    0
Name: colname8, dtype: int64, 0    0
Name: colname9, dtype: int64, 0    0
Name: colname10, dtype: int64, 0    1
Name: colname11, dtype: int64, 0    0
Name: colname12, dtype: int64]
```

**Why am i seeing all this metadata stuff when i clearly appended the numeric value?**

Note that the DataFrame was created via a pd.read_sql_query call.

Comment: You need `values.append(val.tolist())` or `values.append(list(val))` for convert `Series` to list.

Comment: Or maybe need `df.values.T.tolist()` ?

Comment: jupyter-* are irrelevant tags here, please refrain from adding them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need convert values to `numpy array`, transpose and convert to `list`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': ['a','e','g'],
    'B': list(range(3))
})
print (df)
   A  B
0  a  0
1  e  1
2  g  2

L = df.values.T.tolist()
print (L)
[['a', 'e', 'g'], [0, 1, 2]]
```

If need loopy slowier solution convert `Series` to `list`:

```
values = []
for i in range(len(columns)):
        val = df[columns[i]];        
        values.append(val.tolist())
```

If only one row `DataFrame` or need select some row in `df` use [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) for select by position for `Series` and then convert to `list`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [0],
    'B': [3],
    'C' :[1]   
})
print (df)
   A  B  C
0  0  3  1

L = df.values.T.tolist()
print (L)
[[0], [3], [1]]

#select first row
L1 = df.iloc[0].tolist()
print (L1)
[0, 3, 1]
```

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': ['a','e','g'],
    'B': list(range(3))
},index=list('def'))
print (df)
   A  B
d  a  0
e  e  1
f  g  2

#select by index name
L1 = df.loc['f'].tolist()
print (L1)
['g', 2]

#select by position of row
L1 = df.iloc[2].tolist()
print (L1)
['g', 2]
```

Comment: Is this the only way to append to values? Essentially my df only has 1 row.

Comment: I add solution for one row DataFrame to list.

Comment: i was able to get what i think is the correct values (single dimensional array) using the df.iloc[0].tolist(). But now im getting this error, "ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape"

Comment: What is dataframe which return this error? It is empty dataframe, or something else? What return `print (df.iloc[0])` ? What is `print (type(df))`for problematic dataframe? Thanks.